# A nilpotent Lie algebra has an ideal of codimension 1

Tags: lie-algebras, nilpotence

I'm stuck on the next problem from Humphreys:
Let $L$ be nilpotent. Prove that L has an ideal of codimension 1.

Here is my attempt:
I have that $L\neq[L,L]$ (so $[L,L]\subsetneq L$), so $\dim(L/[L,L])\geq 1$. If $\dim(L/[L,L])=1$ then the result follows by taking $I=[L,L]$. Now suppose $\dim(L/[L,L])=n>1$.

Let $\beta=\text{Span}\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n}\}$ be a basis for $L/[L,L]$. Since $L/[L,L]$ is abelian, then $I=\text{Span}\{e_{1},\ldots,e_{n-1}\}$ is an ideal of $L/[L,L]$ with codimension 1. By the correspondence theorem, I corresponds to an ideal of $L$, say $K$, such that $[L,L]\subset K$ (furhtermore: $[L,L]\subset K\subset L$). So, I'm stuck here, how can I show that K has codimension 1?

Also, if we consider $\pi:L\rightarrow L/[L,L]$ the canonical projection, I think that $\pi^{-1}(I)$ has codimension 1 (I know that is an ideal of $L$), but a can't see.

I will apreciate any hint, thanks.

Comment: It's false for $L=0$ but true otherwise, even replacing "nilpotent" with "solvable", and more generally with "with nonzero abelianization".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HINT:

Consider a subspace $K$ such that $[L,L]\subset K$ and $K$ of codimension $1$. It turns out that $K$ is an ideal! Indeed: $[L,K] \subset [L,L]\subset K$.

About your question on codimensions: if $p \colon V \to W$ is a surjective linear map and $W'\subset W$ is a subspace then the codimension of $p^{-1}(W')$ in $V$ is the codimension of $W'$ in $W$. That is some linear algebra.

Answer (score 0):

If you read Humphreys' book, you can use the result of exercise 7(this one should be exercise 8).

Take $K$ be the maximal proper subalgebra of $L$ then we have $K$'s codimension is one and by exercise 7 above, we have $K$ is properly included in $N_L(K)$. By the choice of $K$, we have $N_L(K) = L$ i.e. $K$ is also an ideal of $L$.

Done.

Comment: Let dim $L= n>1$. Gotta argue why $K$'s dimesion should be $n-1$. Any non-zero element $x$ not lying in $K$ spans a proper subalgebra, because $[\mathbb Fx, \mathbb Fx] =0$. So by maximality $\mathbb F x\subset K$, contradiction.