# Equivalent condition for a Lie algebra to be Nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, lie-algebras, nilpotence

In these [notes](http://relaunch.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/perrin/chap5.pdf), the author, N. Perrin, states that a Lie algebra $\frak{g}$ is nilpotent if and only if we can find a decreasing sequence $(\frak{g}_i)_{i=0}^n$ of ideals in $\frak{g}$ such that $\dim\frak{g}_i/\frak{g}_{i+1}=1$ and $[\frak{g},\frak{g}_i]\subset\frak{g}_{i+1}$ for all $i$.

I cannot make any sense of his proof, so I tried proving this on my own. The converse is obvious. When I tried the other implication, I started from the central sequence $(\frak{g}_i)_{i=0}^n$ and said that, if $\frak{g}_i/\frak{g}_{i+1}$ is d-dimensional, then we can find a basis with $d$ elements. Picking a representative for each element of that basis, we get that $\mathfrak{g}_i=\mathbb{C}x_1+\dots+\mathbb{C}x_d+\mathfrak{g}_{i+1}$. So I figured that I could interpolate $\mathfrak{h}_k=\mathbb{C}x_k+\dots+\mathbb{C}x_d+\mathfrak{g}_{i+1}$ between $\frak{g}_i,g_{i+1}$ so the quotients are one-dimensional, but I cannot prove that $\mathfrak{h}_k$ are ideals in all of $\mathfrak{g}$.

I abandoned this idea. Later on, I tried proving that a nilpotent Lie algebra has an ideal of codimension one. I figured that an iteration of this process would yield the result, but apparently I cannot get that the ideals that come from the 2nd application and on of this process are ideals **in $\frak{g}$**. I am stuck, any help is appreciated.

Comment: Every nilpotent Lie algebra has an ideal of codimension one, see [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2462163/a-nilpotent-lie-algebra-has-an-ideal-of-codimension-1?rq=1).

Comment: @DietrichBurde Hello, yes, I know this result but I do not know how to use it, as I say in the final paragraph. Could you please expand on this?

Comment: I see. You wrote "I tried proving that a nilpotent Lie algebras has an ideal of codimension one. I figured .... that would yield the result". So I thought, the problem is the ideal of codimension one.

Comment: @DietrichBurde I see the confusion. Sorry, this was the feasible part, I couldn't figure out how to use this though..

Comment: But the notes give a proof that (i) and (v) are equivalent, right?

Comment: @DietrichBurde Yes but as I say in my post I cannot make any sense of the proof

Comment: @JustDroppedIn sorry, I have a question about the converse, which you said is trivial. Is it because $[\mathfrak{g_i}, \mathfrak{g}] \subset \mathfrak{g_{i+1}}$ can be iterated until reaching $i+1 = n$ and thus it can be concluded that every element in $\mathfrak{g}$ is ad nilpotent (so $\mathfrak{g}$ is nilpotent)? If so, I can’t understand why we need the dimensional hypothesis on the quotients.

Comment: @cip It was trivial to me because the definition of nilpotency is satisfied immediately (check the notes for the definision i was using). That's exactly the point, the converse is like saying definition AND something extra --implies-> definition, which is of course obvious. Sorry, but I have forgotten almost everything about Lie algebras by now.

Comment: Perfect, thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Eventually what I was trying worked after all:

It suffices to interpolate $\mathfrak{h}_k=\mathbb{C}x_k+\dots+\mathbb{C}x_d+\mathfrak{g}_{i+1}$ between $\frak g_i, g_{i+1}$. By the definition of the central series, it is $[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}_i]=\mathfrak{g}_{i+1}$. Therefore, we have
$$[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{h}_k]\subset[\mathfrak{g},\mathfrak{g}_i]=\mathfrak{g}_{i+1}\subset\mathfrak{h}_{k+1}$$
for all $k$, so the desired inclusions hold. Moreover, $\mathfrak{h}_k$ are ideals in $\mathfrak{g}$ and the quotients $\mathfrak{h}_k/\mathfrak{h}_{k+1}$ are obviously one-dimensional.

Comment: I am encounter the same problem. could you be more specific about the index $k$, what is its relation with the index $i$?

Comment: The index $k$ is arbitrary from $1$ to  $d$. I use the same notation as the one used at the question!